# Brew not using right php version (CLI)

Tags: php

I always get stuck on upgrading php... I have done:

```
brew link php@8.1 --force --overwrite
```

If I run it again I get

```
Warning: Already linked: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.9
```

When I run

```
valet use php@8.1 --force
```

and then

```
valet use php@8.1
```

I get

```
Valet is already using version: php@8.1
```

But when I run

```
php -v
```

I get

```
PHP 8.0.22
```

I have also done

```
valet restart
```

and restarted my computer.

Previously in my zshrc I had:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.0/sbin:$PATH"
```

I have commented these out and added:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
```

and then

```
brew services restart php && valet restart
```

If I then run

```
brew doctor
```

I still get:

```
Warning: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /opt/homebrew/sbin.
Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: your tags are incorrect. it's not PHP related question. please fix the tags

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you have to restart the terminal before the new config changes take effect...